# Add theme support for margin

Tags: add-theme-support

Is there a way to use add_theme_support to enable margin option in the Dimensions tab in block editor?

I understand how this can be done in theme.json, but is there a way to do it with `add_theme_support` ?

I was trying out `add_theme_support( 'custom-spacing' );` but it is only enabling padding. I was not able to find any additional options to pass in.

I also tried `add_theme_support( 'appearance-tools' );` but this is not working at all, at least on my WP 6.2, and I also don't see it in [this list](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_theme_support/) although it is [here](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/how-to-guides/themes/theme-support/#appearance-tools).